# Twitter Bootstrap btn-primary Size IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone else noticed strange behaviour by Twitter Bootstrap in IE8 and below?  I have two buttons, as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"/>
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-large"/>
```

The `btn-primary` button is displaying really small, but the button with just `btn btn-large` is large, as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

EDIT:  Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Ran some tests and the input buttons look ok to me, can you post a screenshot or a test case over at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: See the screenshot posted here:
http://s15.postimage.org/pis43f8nv/Untitled.png

Comment: Try this in your browser: http://jsfiddle.net/sCPUe/show/ .. they look ok to me in IE7 and 8.

Comment: Typically any issues you might find with buttons are due to other style sheets, are you including anything other than bootstrap css?

Comment: Andres, your example is showing perfectly.  Jakub must be right, I'll take another look at my other stylesheet!  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMatthews did you modify the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet in any way?

Comment: @AndresIlich Nope, I didn't touch it.

Comment: @ChrisMatthews weird, if you had the default stylesheet , unmodified, included it should not have changed styles. Unless it was a cache issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**from my comment**

> Typically any issues you might find with buttons are due to other
>   style sheets, are you including anything other than bootstrap css?

What you want to do is using CHROME 'right click' on the element, and `inspect`, then review the styles that are applied to that element.

More-often than not, it is other things being inherited or causing conflict. IE is a fickle beast, one I think most of us would rather do without when it comes to CSS/HTML5 ;)

Comment: "IE is a fickle beast, one I think most of us would rather do without when it comes to CSS/HTML5 ;)"

Couldn't agree more! :)

Comment: I checked and there are no other rules other than the bootstrap being applied